# Почему setState действует по разному?

Tags: reactjs, state, render

Имеем вот такой код:

```
    export default function App() {
    let [state, setState] = useState(12)
    setState(12)
    const clickHandler = () => setState(12)
    console.log('render')
    return <>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>sadfasdf</button>
        <h1>Привет</h1>
    </>

}
```

Подскажите, почему setState(12) напрямую вызывает постоянный перерендеринг, в то время как такой же setState в clickHandler  не вызывает перерендеринг

Comment: `setState` обновляет состояние и ставит в очередь на рендер, рендеринг компонента снова вызывает `setState`, который обновляет состояние и ставит в очередь на рендер и так бесконечно. А при клике установка состояния и перерендер выполняется однократно, после клика https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate

Comment: То что вы написали, это и так понятно. Суть вопроса не в том, она такова - в данный момент state = 12. Если я в обработчике события вызываю setState(12), рендер НЕ происходит. если же я вызываю setState(12)  в самой функции рендера, перерендеринг происходит, понятно что при этом зацикливание, но суть вопроса в том - почему установка значения state, равное текущему, в одном случае вызывает перерендеринг, а в другом нет?